# Getting links with certain anchor text using regex

Tags: php, regex, anchor

I'm looking to do a `preg_match_all` to catch the href of a link that has the anchor text of `free file`.

This is what I have so far `<a.+href="(.*)".*>free file</a>` but its not working as I'm getting a error of...

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'f' in
>   /home/aaran/public_html/tests/free_file.php on line 20

PS I'm wanting to match the URL from this:

```
<p> Grab this month's <a href="/item/html5-image-transitions-jquery-plugin/571431?WT.ac=free_file&amp;WT.seg_1=free_file&amp;WT.z_author=pixelentity">free
file</a> from the Canvas category! </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you didn't put delimiters around your expression. PHP requires the expression to be surrounded by some form of valid delimiter. Common ones are:

- `/`, usually used unless there's a particular reason not to do so
- `~`
- `#`

So make sure your `preg_match` starts like this:

```
preg_match('~<a.+href="(.*)".*>free file</a>~', /* ... */
```

Note that I used the tilde as a delimiter because you have a `/` in your expression.